# download an image as a temp file and setting it as pixmap

Tags: python, urllib

I'm downloading a YouTube video thumbnail and saving it as a tempfile. I'm then getting a pixmap out of that tempfile and later I can set it to a label, it will appear for the YouTube video thumbnail.
My problem is that the same method won't work for YouTube #shorts thumbnail, it wont throw any error but the label will be empty. I dont know why

This is an example of a YouTube video thumbnail image url:

`url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MtN1YnoL46Q/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEjCOADEI4CSFryq4qpAxUIARUAAAAAGAElAADIQj0AgKJDeAE=&rs=AOn4CLDlF_ZTyfJ1i9Vw9HqEm5d5D5zL9Q"`

This is an example of a YouTube shorts thumbnail image url:

`url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VT_7UBAf3Vc/2.jpg"`

This is the code that works for the YouTube video thumbnails but not for the shorts

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from urllib.request import urlopen
import base64
import tempfile

url = .......
image = base64.b64encode(urlopen(url).read()).decode("ascii")
imgdata = base64.b64decode(image)
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="wb") as img:
     img.write(imgdata)
     pixmap = QPixmap(img.name)
```

How can I make it work for YouTube shorts image URLs too?

Comment: try removing the parameters at the end of the uri

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags: this question has actually nothing to do with PyQt. Besides, `urlopen` is blocking, and that should ***never*** happen in a UI environment. You either use a QThread subclass with custom signals (but be aware that you cannot create QPixmap in external threads, and you **must** use QImage instead for signals), or use [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), which is asynchronous by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the urllib.parse module to remove the parameters/args from the end of the url.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse  # add parsing funcs
import base64
import tempfile

url = .......
url = urlunparse(list(urlparse(url)[:3]) + ['','',''])  # try removing the arguments
image = base64.b64encode(urlopen(url).read()).decode("ascii")
imgdata = base64.b64decode(image)
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="wb") as img:
     img.write(imgdata)
     pixmap = QPixmap(img.name)
```